# Why has IPv4 only 4 numbers

Tags: ipv4

Yes this sounds stupid, but i couldn't figure it out until now.
Due to Ip exhaustion multiple methods were found to use Ips more efficiently.
But why has no one tried to add a 5th number after the earlier 4?
I mean 127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1.0
Why did we not add more numbers to the Ip if necessary so the exhaustion could be worked around?

--Edit--
What I mean is not just extending the format from 32 bits to 128 bits, but why couldn't we do it dynamic? Why haven't we just said we keep 4 bytes as standard, but we can just enlarge it with some more bytes in case ?

Comment: IP is a protocol which defines a specific format where addresses must fit in a 32-bit number. Change that format and existing clients won't recognize those packets as IP packets anymore.

Comment: An IPv4 address is 32 bits (binary digits) long. Using a different written representation wouldn’t change that binary field width or the number of possible addresses.

Comment: Why didn't we just extend it? IPv4 was designed at a time when we thought that a.) 32bit worth of addresses is way more than we'd ever need and b.) bits on the network were expensive, so we crammed as much info in as few bits of headers as possible. Adding bits to indicate "this uses a bigger address" was consider unnecessary (due to *a*) and wasteful (due to *b*). And we can't just change what IPv4 looks like because tons and tons of hardware and software already has a pretty good idea of what IPv4 looks like and all of those would be wrong if we "just changed it". IPv6 is the solution.

Comment: @JoachimSauer the question was meant when the IPv4 protocol decided to switch to IPv6. This question asked how IPv6 was the solution. I'm terribly sorry i am so bad with writing questions

Comment: I see, so basically the question is: "why is the number of bytes in the address in IPv6 fixed and not dynamic"? Simple answer: there's tons of advantages from having fixed size addresses. One of the first ones is that you can exactly compute the memory requirement of fitting a fixed number of routing entries into memory. If your addresses were variable-length, then indexing into such a table becomes more difficult as well.

Comment: @Joachim And it would probably result in a lot of buffer overflow attacks and the like on essential network gear as that dynamic allocation gets it wrong in a lot of cheap low end implementations…

Comment: @deceze: I thought about mentioning that, but it was already getting pretty busy for a comment ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv4 uses *32-bit* address, its size is standard fixed in the internet layer for different clients to recognize. However with the ipv4 exhaustion, we came out with a new standard, [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6), which uses a much larger *128-bit* address among many other improvements

The numbers you see in an IPv4 address are actually just the 32bit(s) translated into easily read bytes.

### UPDATE

> Why not extending it dynamically?

Let's take a packet: it's merely a stream of bits, this stream of bits is meant to be read by PCs (most of the times) but also by your network equipment, which need to operate on these packets and they need to do so with the minimal latency possible.

So how would a router deal with ~1Gb of data in one sec, without having to do any complex computations (it's just a router, it doesn't pack actual horsepower)? We have a model ([OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)) which specifies layers with standards that are really easy to parse for simple networking appliances. IPv4 is one such standard that works on the [Network layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer). It was defined with fixed size for the address, so a router would basically expect to read 4 bytes (32 bits) as an address and then read something else.

If we needed to make these extensible, then we'd have to reprogram the routers to read the number of bytes for ex. and then read that number of bytes. Sounds easy? It's much faster/cheaper for these poor routers to have a predefined number of bytes that they'll have to read, (which we did in IPv4, increased in IPv6), and we had to reprogram the routers to accept that new standard (IPv6) old routers doesn't recognize IPv6 at all (we did have some fall back mechanisms to ease the transaction).

Comment: I've updated my question: Why didn't we extend the IP dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer the actual question, which everyone else seems not to do:

> What I mean is not just extending the format from 32 bits to 128 bits, but why couldn't 
>   we do it dynamic?

Because this is not how widely published standards work. You need to understand 2 things here:

- IP has to work on super low end hardware or specialized high throughput hardware, do you want to keep things simple to process.
- It is a published standard. Changes will result into serious problems unless EVERYONE can update their processing.

IPv6 was released a LONG time ago and so far it has a very low penetration. What you propose would run into the same issue - unless every involved in an exchange of packets can deal with it, it will be problematic. So, it is problematic and takes a long time.

Yes, we MAY have gone with a dynamic added 5th byte instead of a 128 bit number, but they decided to make ONE update ONCE - and that one got stuck in limbo for many many many many years because people do not upgrade their code without reason. Any smaller update - as you propose - would face the same problem. Unless everyone updates - you have a problem that your new modified protocol is not usable.

Also:

> so how would a router deal with ~1Gb of data in one sec, without having to do any 
>   complex computations (it's just a router, it doesn't pack actual horsepower

Seriously, routers DO pack serious horsepower including specialized chips to handle high end scenarios. SWITCHES are generally low horsepower hardware and price optimized for the lower end, but real routers - you seem to think 1gb is a lot. Routers handle multiple 10gb streams these days as well as updating gigabyte large routing tables via GBP. Serious horsepower involved in higher end routers. I know 100g router/switch combos that actually do IP routing in hardware via ASIC's. That is 100g per port. Mellanox in case. These are layer 2 switches that actually can do full routing, just - well, specialized hardware.

https://www.mellanox.com/related-docs/prod_eth_switches/BR_SN3000_Series.pdf

On the lower end:

https://mikrotik.com/product/CCR1072-1G-8Splus

This is a mid to lower end router. Handles up to 5x10g. 72 core processor included. And this is lower end and has been badmouthed repeatedly for not having enough horsepower on the routing table processing side for GBP. Once you need more throughput even on Mikrotik you go Xeon sort to say.

And noone really cares about data amount there - it is all about PPC - packets per second - regardless how much payload is attached to a package (that the processing just forwards). Because there are a lot of applications that depend on small frequent packets to minimize latency.

Comment: I was talking about home routers, to make a point.... I'm not talking about a >$10k (not even >$500) router

Answer (score -1):

There are a bunch of ways to workaround the IPv4 number exhaustion. Private addresses, network address translations, etc etc.

For instance, what you're proposing already exists, and is in fact IPv6 (0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0). But it isn't backward compatible with IPv4. You can't just add a extra number and expect it to work for older systems, because it won't.

Comment: IPv6 isn't just 6-bytes, IPv6 is actually 16-bytes (0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0)

Comment: that's why it's usually written in hexa (each 2digits is a byte now) (ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff)

Comment: @jalsh ff = 1byte;  ff * 2 * 4 = 16Bytes?

Comment: sorry, my bad ipv6 is sometihng like this
`ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`
but, usually, you'll see something like this:
`ffff:ffff::ffff:ffff` which means:
`ffff:ffff:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:ffff`

Comment: You're right. It's eight groups of 4 hexadecimal digits each.